# jQuery Mobile datebox value undefined

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get the value of a datebox in jQuery Mobile but it's always undefined:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div> <!-- /header -->

      <div data-role="content">
        <label for="input_date">Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="input_date" id="intput_date" data-role="datebox">
        <a href="#" id="input_update" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Update</a>
        <div id="output_pageone"></div>
      </div> <!-- /content -->

      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('vclick', '#input_update', function() {
          var test = $('#input_date').val();
          $('#output_pageone').html('result: ' + test);
        });
      </script> <!-- /script -->
    </div> <!-- /page -->
  </body>
</html>
```

But test is always undefined.

I've put a slider on the page and used

```
test = $('#input_slider').val();
```

which returns the value of the slider, but I can't figure out why I can't get a date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the id of the element.

```
$('#intput_date').val();
```

Comment: Showing my genius once again... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong id.

Your input has an id: **#intput_date**

And your javascript is trying to access: **#input_slider**

It works if correct id is used: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/W8dfx/

```
$(document).on('vclick', '#input_update', function() {
    var test = $('#intput_date').val();
    $('#output_pageone').html('result: ' + test);
});
```